# How to define a function that returns an NSString in Objective-C / Iphone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Hmm i would have thought this would be a little more straightforward..

in my .h file, i'm trying the following

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myViewController : UIViewController {
}
- (int)doStuff;
- (NSString)doMoreStuff;
@end
```

the compiler flags my doMoreStuff but allows doStuff..  any clues?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)doMoreStuff;
```

since all objective-C objects are referenced by pointers.

Comment: d'oh!  you're right.  i missed that.   I would have thought it'd treat strings as primitives like ints, but then again I'm new at this